# Automatically precompile assets before pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake

Is it possible to automatically precompile my assets in a Rails app before pushing out to Heroku? I always forget to do it, so it would be nice if when I typed `git push heroku master`, it would first run `rake assets:precompile ; git commit add . ; git commit -a -m "Precompile."`, or something to that effect.

Has anyone achieved such a solution? Possibly without hooks? Though I suspect that is the only way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally figured this out. I was indeed on the Cedar stack. The problem was that I had checked my `public` directory into Git, and when I pushed to Heroku, it realized that `public` existed, and thus assumed I precompiled. Running `git rm -r public` and adding `public/**` to my `.gitignore`, then pushing, fixes the problem.

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you might not be on [Heroku's Cedar Stack](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar)? If you're using the asset pipeline (Rails -v >= 3.1), cedar provides [three options](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#the_asset_pipeline) for compiling assets.

From the [docs](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#compiling_assets_during_slug_compilation):

> If you have not compiled assets locally, we will attempt to run the
>   `assets:precompile` task during slug compilation.

Answer (score 3):

You could always alias `heroku` or something similar to `rake assets:precompile ; git commit add . ; git commit -a -m "Precompile." ; git push heroku master` in your bash profile
ie

```
#in ~/.bash_profile 
alias precompile_push='rake assets:precompile ; git commit add . ; git commit -a -m "Precompile." ; git push heroku master'
```

Comment: If this is a part of your deploy process, I would recommend making that a script in your codebase.

Answer (score 1):

On the cedar stack, it will do this during slug compilation. I recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a gem that run as daemon and automatically pull changes from a Git repo, precompiles assets, commit and push back.

https://github.com/nectify/rails-precompile2git/