# Rails: Precompile for Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, precompile

Before deploying a new version of my app on Heroku, I need to do this in my console (for css and js to work on Heroku): `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.

I just picket this code line from a forum, and I my questions is:

1) Why do I need to do this?
2) Is it possible to implement something more permanent in my Rails code so it does this precompiling automatically (so I don't need to write it manually every time I do some changes in my css or js files)?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Why do I need to do this?

There are lot of `js` files and `css` file in rails app generally. The above command compress and minified all those files which will reduce the number of requests that  browser makes to render a web page. Web browsers are limited in the number of requests that they can make in parallel, so fewer requests can mean faster loading for your application.

[More](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html%E2%80%8E)

> 2) Is it possible to implement something more permanent in my Rails code so it does this precompiling automatically (so I don't need to write it manually every time I do some changes in my css or js files)?

Yes. Heroku automatically compiles your assets if you dont include `public/assets/manifest.yml` for rails 3 and in rails 4 it is `public/assets/manifest-<md5 hash>.json`

[More](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline)

Related Answer : [Automatically precompile assets before pushing to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273900/automatically-precompile-assets-before-pushing-to-heroku)

Comment: Thanks for answering. But is this the best way to precompile automatically before pushing to Heroku (this seems a bit cumbersome)?

Comment: yes. that is, not sure why you think it is cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

In your production.rb

`config.assets.compile = true`